# How to make a primary key start from 1000?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

```
create table tablename (
    id integer unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ....
    primary key id
);
```

I need the primary key to start from 1000.

I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If your table has already been created with an auto-increment. so you can use

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

otherwise put the `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;` in your `CREATE TABLE`

it goes before the final
);

Answer (score 42):

You can use ALTER TABLE to accomplish this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

If you want it as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, just put it after the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Comment: Is there a way we can do this in model definition?

Answer (score 7):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

little bit about your code **NOT NULL** is redundant as primary key specifies NOT NULL & UNIQUE on id.

answering your primary question for auto incrementing to start from 1000 execute the following SQL query.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id integer unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ....
    primary key (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

If you want to alter the existing table for id to start from 1000 then there are two ways you can achieve this.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename  MODIFY id int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Answer (score -4):

Well in such a situation, i simply open up my mysql client software and i type 1000, etc right in the primary key field. The record getting inserted will have ids greater than 1000 now.