# How to force primary key in ActiveRecord with PostgreSQL to jump start from a specific integer value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, primary-key

From this: [How to make a primary key start from 1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130635/how-to-make-a-primary-key-start-from-1000)  It seems that I need to issue the SQL command: ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
But I only have been dealing with the database through the ActiveRecord abstraction.  Is there a way to achieve it via active record?  Either at the time of migration or on the fly when creating new record on the database?

I have tried both the following and failed:

```
@record= myRecord.new
while @record.id < 1000 do
    @record= myRecord.new
end
```

It is inefficient but it would just happen once, yet Rails report that @record.id is nil so cannot do the < comparasion
and so I try to save the @record first and then see what id (primary key) value it has been assigned by the database

```
@record.save
if @record.id <1000
    @record.id = 1000 + @record.id
    @record.save!             
end
```

Somehow rails reports back that one of the unique field in @record is already there so cannot save the @record again.

EDIT:  My bad, the above is MySQL command... for PostgreSQL, it seems to be something along the line ( http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2006-10/msg01417.php ):

```
 SELECT setval('id_seq',100111);
```

However, I tried to run it on the Ruby console of my deployment environment (shared database on Heroku) and I just got !Internal server error  back :-(
my ruby class is called:

```
class Mytable < ActiveRecord::Base
```

so I run this command:

```
Mytable.connection.execute('SELECT setval('id_seq', 1000)')
```

and got Internal server error  (tried with both 'id' and 'id_seq' in the above command)
But it may be some sort of Ruby on Heroku specific issue that is causing the trouble, so I  would investigate and posts another question instead of changing this one. Thanks!

Addition related PostgreSQL command materials:

http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2008/03/mysql-versus-postgresql-adding-an-auto-increment-column-to-a-table.html

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2006-10/msg01417.php

[How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

Answer (score 4):

You can execute raw sql like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000');
```

Or from any descendant of ActiveRecord::Base (i.e. any model class), like this:

```
MyRecord.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in PostgreSQL this will fail as there is no auto_increment = in the alter table.  What you need is to find the sequence being used and then issue a command like "select setval('seqname',1000);"

Comment: @ScottMarlowe, you may well be right, I just took the OP's word on the required literal SQL since I am not familiar with PostgreSQL. If you are familiar with it, maybe you can post a better answer than mine?

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarlowe !  I have also find the PostgreSQL command before I read your comment.  I am using the default ActiveRecord auto generated Primary Key for the class, so it is just named "id", but I don't know the name of the sequence that is associated with its value generation.

Comment: Ben Lee, your answer was essentially the right one, how to run raw sql.  I just added the last bit.  As for the sequence name, can you connect in any way to the db to run a \d tablename and see?  If not, it usually goes by the standard naming convention of tablename_colname_seq.  So something like select setval('table_col_seq',1000);