# Set alternative pk in Django

Tags: python, django, primary-key, django-database

I would like to make Django generate 6+ digits number id's for one `Model`. I don't want to start from zero but I want this id's to be clear and readable by users. So the good one is for example: **658975**

How to do that?

I've tried this:

```
class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

But `uuid` generates huge sequences which is not user-friendly.

Do you have any advices? Maybe setting minimum number of autoincrement pk would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use pk+random number to show to the user and keeping the rest of the logic same ?

Else here you go [How to make a primary key start from 1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130635/how-to-make-a-primary-key-start-from-1000)

Write a one of migration for this.

Comment: This is not a bad idea... but it's too much refactoring/rewriting code. For example get requests with id etc... too vulnerable to making mistakes in code.  But if nothing else, I would try this.

Answer (score 0):

The best options to set the primary key to start from `100000`. For example(MySQL),

```
ALTER TABLE django_app_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000
```

Since these commands are depends on the database vendor, it is better to write a our own custom migration using the Django migration [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own).