# how to set the auto_increment starting value in MySQL using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried several ways of setting the auto increment value on the primary key ID on a table with no luck.

Doesn't work for me...

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000,
```

Tried this...

```
UPDATE tablename SET id = id + 10000;
```

Tried this..

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Tried this..

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    ...
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

[image]

What is the proper way to set this when creating a table using SQL?

Comment: check this  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2130648/5830872

Comment: Those are not working for me.

Comment: share your complete table schema ?

Comment: There really is no good reason why you would ever want to do this. That said, the procedure is straightforward

Answer (score 3):

On the creation of the table you can use these SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    ...
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

But, if the table is already created, you can make an `ALTER TABLE` to let the `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequence start with another value, use the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

You can find more on [using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Okay, @codeRed, in what sense is it "not working?"  The answer seems correct.

Comment: In the sense that none of these options are working for me. Either phpmyadmin is spitting out errors, or the numbers are always starting at 1. Im not saying they aren't going to work for someone else or that they are not correct, for some reason it just isn't happening. If I knew why, I wouldn't be here.